# awk show just digits

Tags: bash, awk

I have command in `awk`:

```
awk '$0 !~ /[a-z]/ && $0 != 0' input.txt >> output.txt
```

So my input is something like this:

```
123214
wedsd
sda25567
ssdf
!@!@#@%
```

And my output is:

```
123214
!@!@#@%
```

I think I am doing something wrong with `awk`.

I want awk just show me digits, What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you exclude letter if what you want is to include digits?

Comment: You are right...Could you possibly help me? I am new in `awk`

Comment: Do you understand what the command does at all, or did you just copy/paste it from somewhere?

Comment: What do you like to have as an output on what rule.

Comment: I have many thing in my input file..I want awk just show me lines that only are digits

Comment: @Mat You are right...I copt/paste it... I am new in awk really

Comment: Then if you want to learn it you should learn it. That's done by reading documentation/tutorials/books, not by getting people to spoon-feed you stuff to copy/paste.

Comment: Thanks :) ..But I am in hurry now/// I do learn it.. thank you

Comment: To test for digit only, use anchor.  Se my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `!@!@#@%` does not contain `a-z` and its not `0`
That is why you get hits on it.

To get only numbers, use anchor:

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]+$/'  file
123214
```

or

```
awk '/^[0-9]+$/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
awk '/^[0-9]+$/ && $0 != 0 {print}' input.txt >> output.txt
```